# Abstracting a method common to subclasses but it uses subclass specific types

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have `ElectricCar` and `DieselCar` classes which inherits from `Vehicle`.
They have `ElectricEngine` and `DieselEngine` respectively.

Both engine classes have the `Start` method. Originally I implemented the `StartAllEngines()` in both car subclasses, but I found it highly repetitive, so I want to abstract it in the base `vehicle` class.

The problem is, **how do I define the type of `engines` in the base class?** `dynamic` is an option but I dont feel very safe using it.

Or **I should not abstract the method?** But then it violates the DRY principle.

```
public class Vehicle{
    protected List<???Engine> engines; // What should be the type?

    public void StartAllEngines (){
        foreach (???Engine engine in this.engines){
            engine.Start();
        }
    }
}

public class ElectricCar: Vehicle{
    public ElectricCar(){
        this.engines = List<ElectricEngine>();
    }
}

public class DieselCar: Vehicle{
    public DieselCar(){
        this.engines = List<DieselEngine>();
    }
}

public class ElectricEngine: Engine {...}
public class DieselEngine: Engine {...}
```

Comment: your `List<Engine>` seems odd.  how many engines can 1 vehicle have (autos, not boats, yachts, planes or trains)?

Comment: @Plutonix sorry, just an example haha! It can be anything like doors, headlamps, wheels, etc

Comment: Doesnt matter.  Why would the base class store a collection of anything implemented by the derived classes?

Comment: Its because I saw the `StartAllEngines` method repeating in each vehicle subclass, so I wanted to move it to base class. But the method itself needs to refer to the subclass-specific properties, so I created a field in the base class to let the derived class put `ElectricEngine` etc to it. I am still wondering if it is a good idea to do so

Comment: But the *point* of an interface or derived class is that those methods may require different steps.  The Diesel car may need to invoke `PumpPedalTwice()` first, then something else before `TurnIgnition()`.  How would the base class know that? Besides if I  wanted to start `thisRedCar` would I have to `StartAllEngines()` to do that?

Comment: OK I think I got your point. The base class should be ignorant of the derived class. I should not have reduced the code just because they "Look similar".

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic parameter in the base class w/ `Engine` as the constraint:

```
public class Vehicle<TEngine> where TEngine: Engine
{
    protected List<TEngine> engines = new List<TEngine>();

    public void StartAllEngines (){
        foreach (TEngine engine in this.engines){
            engine.Start();
        }
    }
}

public class ElectricCar: Vehicle<ElectricEngine>
{
    public ElectricCar(){
    }
}

public class DieselCar: Vehicle<DieselEngine>
{
    public DieselCar(){
    }
}

public class ElectricEngine: Engine {...}
public class DieselEngine: Engine {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Plutonix said, strange having a list of engines in a base class, makes no sense

```
public class Vehicle{

    protected Engine engine;

    public void Start (){
        engine.Start();
    }
}

public class ElectricCar : Vehicle
{
    public ElectricCar(){
        engine = new ElectricEngine();
    }

    public void Start()
    {

    }
}

public class DieselCar: Vehicle
{

    public DieselCar(){
        engine = new DieselEngine();
    }
}

public class ElectricEngine : Engine
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        //Start Electric Engine
    }
}
public class DieselEngine: Engine {
    public override void Start()
    {
        //Start Diesel Engine
    }
}

public abstract class Engine
{
    //Alternatively use virtual, depending on what you want to achieve...
    public abstract void Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an `IEngine` interface that exposes a `Start` method that is then inherited by `ElectricEngine` and `DieselEngine`

Eg.

```
public interface IEngine
{
    void Start();
}

public class ElectricEngine : IEngine {

    public void Start()
    {
        // start code
    }
}

public class Vehicle{
    protected List<IEngine> engines;

    public void StartAllEngines (){
        foreach (IEngine engine in this.engines){
            engine.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference if I replace `IEngine` with the original `Engine` base class that has the abstract method `Start()`? I only know that the `interface` differs to an `abstract class` by not allowing to implement method...

Comment: There would be no real difference, but it makes more sense to have an interface if there is only one abstract method. Of course, you could have `IEngine` -> `BaseEngine` -> `ElectricEngine`.